# Improper integral and existence

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> If $a,b\in\mathbb{R}, a<b$ and $f:\{x\in\mathbb{R}:a<x\le b\}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, define the improper integral $\displaystyle\int^{b}_{+a}f(x)\,dx$ to be $\displaystyle\lim_{y\to a}\int^b_yf(x)dx$. Show that if $g$ is another continuous real valued function on the set $\{x\in \mathbb{R}:a<x\le b\}$ such that $|f(x)|<g(x)$ for all $x$ in this set and $\displaystyle\int^{b}_{+a}g(x)\,dx$ exists, then $\displaystyle\int^{b}_{+a}f(x)\,dx$ exists.So I need to show that $\displaystyle\int^{b}_{+a}f(x)\,dx$ exists if there exists an $\alpha<1$ such that $(x-a)^{\alpha}f$ is bounded on $(a,b)$.

So I have $g(x)\ge 0$ since $|f(x)|<g(x)$ and that $\displaystyle\int^{b}_{+a}g(x)\,dx = \displaystyle\lim_{y\to a}\int^b_yg(x)dx$ exists. Now pick $\epsilon>0$ then there exists an $l$ such that $\int^{l_2}_{l_1}g(x)dx<\epsilon$ for all $l_2>l_1>l$. Since $|f(x)|<g(x)$ we have $\displaystyle\int|f(x)|dx<\int g(x)dx<\epsilon$. So $\displaystyle\int|f(x)|dx$ is bounded for some $M$. Hence, $\displaystyle\int f(x)dx<M$.

But how can I show that that $\displaystyle\int^{b}_{+a}f(x)\,dx$ exists if there exists an $\alpha<1$ such that $(x-a)^{\alpha}f$ is bounded on $(a,b)$.

Comment: Is the last sentence a separate question? That is, are you asking something more in that sentence than what is in the quoted part that starts the post?

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, that is correct. I was trying to prove it by showing there exists an $\alpha<1$ such that $(x-a)^{\alpha}f
$ is bounded but your proof is more intuitively clear.

Comment: I thought you might have somehow arrived at that, but I couldn't see how it followed from existence of the improper integral. It could stand alone as a separate question: can one show that $(x-a)^{\alpha}f(x)$ bounded implies the improper integral exists?

Comment: user104235: I noticed you removed "accept" on my answer below. Is there something more to explain the problem which you'd like to see

Comment: @coffeemath Oops! I didn't mean to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We express $f(x)$ as the difference between its positive and negative parts, $f(x)=f_p(x)-f_n(x),$ where $f_p(x)=\max(0,f(x))$ and $f_n(x)=-\min(0,f(x)).$ Note that each of $f_p,f_n$ is continuous given that $f$ is. Also note that each is bounded above by $g(x)$ assuming $|f(x)|<g(x)$ on $(a,b].$ Now for $f_p$ we define
$$H(y)=\int_y^b f_p(x)\ dx$$
and note as $y \to a^+$ that $H(y)$ is a monotone increasing function bounded above by $L=\int_{+a}^b g(x)\ dx.$ It follows that $\lim_{y \to a^+} H(y)$ exists, which means the (improper) integral of the positive part of $f(x)$ over $(a,b]$ converges. The same argument works to show the integral of the negative part converges, and since $f$ is the difference of them, it's integral converges also.

Comment: But I do have a question. You noted that each of $f_p,f_n$ is continuous given that $f$ is but what if $f(x)=1/\sqrt x$ on $(0,1]$? Would that still be true?

Comment: If $f(x)=1/\sqrt(x)$ then $f_p=f$ since $f$ is already positive on $(0,1]$. Here the integral converges to 2. Even if $f(x)=1/x^2$ so that the integral diverges, we still have $f_p=f$ bot this time there is no $g$ with $f \le g$ and the $g$ integral comverging, so no contradiction from this case either.